# How to play youtube/vimeo video within the application in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube, uiwebview, vimeo

I am building an application where I want to play video from url like Youtube, Vimeo, Direct url. I am making custom player using AVPlayer to play a video from a direct url of video clip(like www.abc/play.mp4). But later I faced a huge issue to play youtube & vimeo video. And after searching a lot I found these link where it says without using UIWebview I can't play a Youtube link:

[Play YouTube videos with MPMoviePlayerController instead of UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779511/play-youtube-videos-with-mpmovieplayercontroller-instead-of-uiwebview/1781192#1781192)

[Playing video from youtube link without UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18287889/playing-video-from-youtube-link-without-uiwebview/18288018#18288018)

So I just used this code:

```
NSString *youTubeVideoHTML = @"<html><head><style>body{margin:0;}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:\'100%%\', height:'200px', videoId:\'%@\', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady } }); } function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } </script> </body> </html>";

NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:youTubeVideoHTML, videoId];
self.embedded_player_view.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

[self.embedded_player_view loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL]];
```

***Now when I click on youtube/Vimeo video link from tableview its playing the video with the default player i.e. quicktime player. Its not running the video within the UIWebview frame itself.
But I want to show the video in the 1st half of the screen i.e my UIWebview frame. Is that possible?***

In my app I can see this:

### **when clicking on red play button I can see the video in full screen in quicktime player like this:**

[image]   [image]

### **But I want to show the video within the same webView frame not via quick time player. It should play like this:**

[image]

Same does in [MusicTube](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/musictube-free-free-music/id632522670?mt=8) and [PlayTube](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/playtube-free-videos-from/id661624671?mt=8).

Or is there any other way to achieve the same? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any solution for this issue? I am also trying to display videos from youtuble,vimeo and facing the same issue.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nope. Got some solution for youtube but sorry to say not for vimeo. @AkbariDipali

Answer (score 14):

[image][image]

I've used [this class](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController) just for that.

The video you see inside the `UIViewController` is playable in its current size.

That's the only code I've used:

```
UIView *videoContainerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 320, 200)];
    [self.view addSubview:videoContainerView];        
    XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController *videoPlayerViewController = [[XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController alloc] initWithVideoIdentifier:@"_OBlgSz8sSM"];
    [videoPlayerViewController presentInView:videoContainerView];
    [videoPlayerViewController.moviePlayer play];
```

Comment: Let me know one thing. Isn't it a violation of YouTube's policy?

Comment: @Avijit I never bothered to read YouTube policy. I got a few apps using the above in the AppStore right now so if there's a problem apple doesn't seem to mind.

Comment: @Avijit I don't know. I only used it for youtube.

Comment: actually there is list of songs for youtube and vimeo. I have to play both of them.

Comment: And the seekbar isn't showing there. I can see only play button and a full screen icon in the player. But there is neither the seekbar nor the total time and progress time as you have shown in your picture.

Comment: @Avijit Recheck your code. The images were taken from the iPhone simulator, Not photoshop.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45371/discussion-between-avijit-and-sha)

Comment: Its not playing the vimeo ideo at all. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: @Avijit did u get any solution for the same? My prob is similar, am using XCdYoutbe third party, SOme songs its able to play and some it cannot play(specially from channels like vevo and all). what exactly you have implemnted, and I heard using XCDYOutube thirdpaty is discouraged by the Apple. Please Help

Comment: come on here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45803/mobileappfactoryios-android for detail discussion @Jeev

Comment: @Segev still , this one works like a charm . simplest way to implement . thanks, you saved my lot of time .

Answer (score 7):

For Vimeo player you can check this link https://github.com/lilfaf/YTVimeoExtractor it plays the video in real player and if you want to run the video in uiwebview,here is the code for that https://stackoverflow.com/a/15918011/1865424.

Pass you URL of YouTube Video in “urlStr”.

```
//In .h file
UIWebView *videoView;
// In .m file

videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 385)];

[self embedYouTube :urlStr  frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 385)];

[self.view addSubview:videoView];

// methos to embed URL in HTML & load it to UIWebView

- (void)embedYouTube:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame

{

NSString* embedHTML = @”\

<html><head>\

<style type=\”text/css\”>\

body {\

background-color: transparent;\

color: white;\

}\

</style>\

</head><body style=\”margin:0\”>\

<embed id=\”yt\” src=\”%@\” type=\”application/x-shockwave-flash\” \

width=\”%0.0f\” height=\”%0.0f\”></embed>\

</body></html>”;



NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

if(videoView == nil) {

videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

[self.view addSubview:videoView];

}

[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

}
```

Courtsey :- http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=641

Hope This Will Help You Out.
If this doesn't help you out please check out these links:-

http://blog.softwareispoetry.com/2010/03/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-your.html

https://gist.github.com/darkredz/5334409

http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/open-source-library-for-easily-playing-a-youtube-video-in-an-mpmovieplayer

Comment: Nope nothing really helps me.

Comment: Nope not yet. @popeye

Comment: @Avijit you can check this link for vimeo..http://stackoverflow.com/a/14643632/1865424
If still didn't work let me know.

Comment: When I used your vimeo link it just played using the default player in iPhone not within the webview(as I expected). Not getting any useful way to play the video within the webview :( .

Comment: @Avijit i have deleted the URL after Sometime..you download it from here..http://www.sendspace.com/file/jyl7lj

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna play youtube, here's a link to youtube player [project](https://github.com/pbernery/PBYouTubeVideoViewController) on github, It's really helpful. and yes it is possible to play it in your uiwebview, just give the webview the url and tell it to load, it shouldn't open in the default player, as far as i believe at least.

Comment: Ok checking it. And let you know the state in few minutes.

Comment: Nope it was again opening in default player. Not in webview frame.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the Vimeo but for youtube videos you can use [HCYouTubeParser](https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser) to fetch mp4 urls for the youtube videos which can be later played on AVPlayer or MpMoviePlayerVC as per requirements.

Answer (score 2):

I used youtube and vimeo in my Project, I share my codings for you it will very hopeful for you

in my view controller.m

```
//Button action

- (IBAction)importAudioClip:(id)sender
{
flag = 0;
customActionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]initWithTitle:@"Select Audio/Video from:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"YouTube",@"Vimeo", nil];
[customActionSheet showInView:self.view];

}


#pragma ActionSheet Delegate Methods
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  NSLog(@"CLiekc button is %i",buttonIndex);

 if([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:@"Select Audio/Video from:"])
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            videoStatus=0;

            webView.hidden = NO;

            [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.youtube.com"]]];
            NSLog(@"Taking from Youtube");

        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            videoStatus=1;
            UIAlertView *alertView=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Vimeo" message:@"Please enter Vimeo Username" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
            alertView.tag=123;
            alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
            [alertView show];

        }
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (alertView.tag==123)
    {
    if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        templateText=[[UITextField alloc]init];
        templateText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        templateText.autocapitalizationType=UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
        templateText.delegate=self;
        if ([templateText.text length]!=0)
        {
            NSString *str=[templateText.text capitalizedString];
            NSLog(@"Str== %@",str);
            [self getVimeoDetails:str];

        }
    }
}
}


-(void)getVimeoDetails:(NSString*)userName
{
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://vimeo.com/api/v2/%@/videos.json",userName]]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
NSString *resSrt = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"The value is==%@",resSrt);
vimeoDetailsArray =(NSArray*) [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&err];
NSLog(@"jsonObject== %i",[vimeoDetailsArray count]);
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[responseData bytes] length:[responseData length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"the reply == %@",theReply);
if(response)
{
    if (vimeoDetailsArray==NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"its Null");
        NSLog(@"null response== %@",response);
        //                     UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theReply] delegate:self
        //                                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        //                     [alert show];
        // [self performSelector:@selector(showAlertMessage:theReply withTitle:@"Alert!!!") withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
        vimeoVideoTable.hidden=YES;
        [self showAlertMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",theReply] withTitle:@"Alert!!!"];
    }
    else
    {
        [self createTableView];
        vimeoVideoTable.hidden=NO;
        [vimeoVideoTable reloadData];
        NSLog(@"got response== %@",response);
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"faield to connect");
}


if ([responseData length] == 0 && err == nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
}
else if (err != nil){

    if ([[err description] rangeOfString:@"The Internet connection appears to be offline"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSLog(@"string does not contain ");
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Alert!!!" message:@"Please Check your Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
    NSLog(@"Error = %@", err);
}

}

-(void)createTableView
{
if (vimeoVideoTable !=nil)
{
    [vimeoVideoTable removeFromSuperview];
    vimeoVideoTable=nil;
}
vimeoVideoTable=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 300, self.view.bounds.size.height-100)];
[vimeoVideoTable setDelegate:self];
[vimeoVideoTable setHidden:YES];
[vimeoVideoTable setDataSource:self];
[self.view addSubview:vimeoVideoTable];
//[vimeoVideoTable reloadData];

}
```

Comment: if you dont mine, i add the view controller.h and view controller.m full code for you

Comment: where is your full viewController.h and viewController.m

Comment: can you please come here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/ios-android-devs

Comment: how to i reply in chat room, there is no option for typing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45793/discussion-between-avijit-and-anbu-karthik)

Comment: just hold on friend i created a new project for you

Answer (score 1):

I definitely suggest [youtube_ios_player_helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper), "sponsored by" [Google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper).

```
import youtube_ios_player_helper

class YTViewController: YTPlayerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var player: YTPlayerView!

    // MARK: - Public properties -

    var videoID = "k_okcNVZqqI"

    // MARK: - View life cycle -

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.player.delegate = self
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.load()
        self.player.fadeOut()
    }

    /**
     Play video with the relative youtube identifier.
     */
    func load() {
        Utils.showHUD(self.view)
        let options = ["playsinline" : 1]
        self.player.loadWithVideoId(self.videoID, playerVars: options)
    }

    /**
     Stop video playing.
     */
    func stop() {
    }

    // MARK: - YOUTUBE video player delegate -

    func playerViewDidBecomeReady(playerView: YTPlayerView) {
        self.player.playVideo()
    }

    func playerView(playerView: YTPlayerView, didChangeToState state: YTPlayerState) {
        switch state {
        case .Playing:
            self.player.fadeIn(duration: 0.5)
            Utils.hideHUD(self.view)
            print("Started playback")
            break;
        case .Paused:
            print("Paused playback")
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] ;
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendString:@"<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/84403700?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"1024\" height=\"768\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];


[viewWeb loadHTMLString:html baseURL:urlMovie];
```

Comment: I get message "This video cannot be played with your current setup"

Answer (score 0):

I used the following method to solve the same problem successfully.

Use [youtube-ios-player-helper](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper) and add the code:

```
[_playerView loadWithVideoId:@"DmTzboEqfNk" playerVars:@{
                                                         @"playsinline" : @1
                                                         }];
```

You can find more vars in [Youtube > IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 0):

I have used **WKWebView** in storyboard with constraints and added code :

```
func playVideo() {

if yourLink.lowercased().contains("youtu.be"){
    getVideo(videoCode: yourVideoCode)
    if let range = yourLink.range(of: "be/"){
        let videoId = yourLink[range.upperBound...].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        getVideo(videoCode: videoId)
    }
} else if yourLink.lowercased().contains("youtube.com"){
    if let range = yourLink.range(of: "?v="){
        let videoId = yourLink[range.upperBound...].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
        getVideo(videoCode: videoId)
    }
} else if yourLink.lowercased().contains("vimeo.com") {
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: yourLink)
    webKitView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    webKitView.load(URLRequest(url: url as URL))
}
}

func getVideo(videoCode: String) {
    guard
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoCode)")
    else { return }
    webKitView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
}
```

To get videoId from youtube/Vimeo links, please refer to :

[Youtube Video Id from URL - Swift3](http://Youtube%20Video%20Id%20from%20URL%20-%20Swift3)

[Regex to get vimeo video id in swift 2](http://Regex%20to%20get%20vimeo%20video%20id%20in%20swift%202)

Hope will help! :)