# margin on youtube iframe in iOS

Tags: ios, iframe, uiwebview, youtube

I'm having a `UIWebView` with the following code:
`<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OsSZ4u7Sz6s" frameborder="0"></iframe>`

The thing is the the video preview is offest by a few pixels (see image)

I checked with `recursiveDescription` The `UIWebView` itself is in the right place (0,0,320,180)

How can I make it tight?
[image]

**Edit**:
Apparently it happens on Vimeo iframe as well -so the problem is not youtube specific but iframe specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Margins and paddings needs to be reseted.

```
NSString *yourHtml = @"<html><head><title>.</title><style>body,html,iframe{margin:0;padding:0;}</style></head><body><iframe width=\"100%%\"  height=\"250\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/OsSZ4u7Sz6s\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:yourHtml baseURL:nil];
```

If you want more flexibility with your videos you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21140674/1578927) that uses a [3rd party class](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit).

Comment: thanks! Just fix you code yourHtml/embedHTML in case someone copy pastes without noticing :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `webView` is adding the margins because you have no body in your html. Just add a body with no margins:

```
<body style='margin:0px;'><iframe ...></iframe></body>
```

And that's it.

However, if you allow me to say it, it looks nice with a white margin :D you would just need to adjust the size of the iframe.

Hope it helps!